# Very strange GUI problem

Tags: dual-boot, gui

I'm having a very strange problem in Ubuntu 13.04:
[image: GUI problem]

I can only boot into the cairo-dock session and as you can see, some of the screen is missing.  Another issue is that the window borders (with the close, minimize, maximize) is missing.  It only did this once before during the upgrade, but worked on the next boot.  I didn't install any packages my last session, only an hour or two of VMs.  So now I am stuck with Winows 8 :(.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the window compositor and decorator (compiz) is not running. It's probably crashing.

The black areas are "transparent" areas requiring a window compositor running.

Just to get you working again, install the package `gnome-panel` from the terminal. After booting, without logging in, press Control+Alt+F1, login in the console and use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Once you've installed `gnome-panel`, reboot or go back to the login screen with Alt+F7 and choose the session Gnome Classic (no effects).

To get compiz working again, so you can run Unity and Cairo-dock properly, we have to determine what's going wrong. That would be probably one of these:

- Compiz is not installed properly. Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz` from a terminal to make sure that compiz is installed.
- Your user profile has some bad configuration for Compiz. Create a new user and try to login with that user on Cairo Dock or Unity. If that succeeds, you'll have to [reset the Compiz configuration on your user](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html) to fix it.
- Your graphic drivers are not installed properly or are having some trouble running compiz. Run `compiz --replace | tee output_compiz.txt` from the Gnome Classic session to see what's going on. Paste here the generated file `output_compiz.txt` Please add what graphics card, driver are you using.

Please notice that, at any moment, you can login into a console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and run this command to kill your session:

```
killall gnome-session
```

This comes in handy if you're having trouble with the window compositor/decorator and want to go back to the login screen. Press Alt+F7 or Alt+F8 to go back to the graphical session after doing this.

Comment: Thanks!  The first option worked almost perfectly.  For some reason, I am now missing terminal (except for Cairo one) and virtualbox, but it shows they are both installed.  I will make this a new thread if I need to.

Comment: (Sorry, forgot to add this). I also get a blinking underscore on every other boot after grub

Comment: The terminal package is `gnome-terminal`, and virtualbox depends, but the package contains the word `virtualbox` for sure. Do `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox | grep ii` and if you get no results, it's NOT installed. The same for `gnome-terminal`. The blinking underscore seems like a problem with your graphics card. Please post another question about that detailing your graphics card, what driver are you using, etc.

Comment: The blinking underscore was trying to find the HDD.  It worked after a minute or two.  I also just noticed all unity apps (including the terminal) are missing.  The session is also missing.  Thanks for the help

Comment: So just install the package `ubuntu-desktop`. Everything should be fixed then.

Comment: All my problems are fixed.  Thanks for all the help!!